# issue monitoring hadoop response

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, ganglia, gmetad

I am using `ganglia` to monitor `Hadoop`. `gmond` and `gmetad` are running fine. When I telnet on `gmond` port (8649) and when I telnet `gmetad` on its `xml` answer port, I get no `hadoop` data. How can it be ?

```
cluster {
  name = "my cluster"
  owner = "Master"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = "unspecified"
}

host {
  location = localhost
}

udp_send_channel {
  #bind_hostname = yes 
  #mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
  host = localhost
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}

udp_recv_channel {
  #mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
  port = 8649
  retry_bind = true
  # Size of the UDP buffer. If you are handling lots of metrics you really
  # should bump it up to e.g. 10MB or even higher.
  # buffer = 10485760
}

tcp_accept_channel {
  port = 8649
  # If you want to gzip XML output
  gzip_output = no
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the issue. It was related to the `hadoop` metrics properties. I set up `ganglia` in the `hadoop-metrics.properties` but I had to set up `hadoop-metrics.properties` config file. Now `ganglia` throws correct metrics.